Setting the JoyUI theme based on system preference
I was looking over the JoyUI Dark mode documentation at https://mui.com/joy-ui/customization/dark-mode/ and I'm having a hard time finding ways to set the theme based on system preference. I am using Next.js v14 and my root layout is as follows (same as in documentation):
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <InitColorSchemeScript />
    <CssVarsProvider>
      <CssBaseline />
      {children}
    </CssVarsProvider>
  </body>
</html>

extendTheme({ colorSchemeSelector: 'media' }) does not work, there is no 'colorSchemeSelector' property on that object. I did find a similarly-named prop on CssVarsProvider, however setting it to 'media' does not appear to work.
I see the useColorScheme hook which returns a { mode, systemMode } object, but apparently systemMode is undefined by default unless mode is set to 'system'. So I guess if I want to do system by default I need to use the other hook to set mode to system on first render? This seems overly complicated to me & could maybe cause problems with flickering given that I am using SSR. I feel like there should be a 'mode' property I can set, maybe on the CssVarsProvider component.

<InitColorSchemeScript defaultMode="system" /> accomplishes what I wanted
